# How to make both UITextFields content equal at the same time?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ios5, ios4, ios-simulator

I have some UITextFields and one button, Can anyone tell me how to make both textfields  (first Street Address field and Street Address field below Same As Above button) content equal  at the same time if my button (Same As Above) is checked (I m using a boolean variable isSameAsAboveChecked on button click and making value Yes and No on respective actions).

Means If Same As Above button is checked, and i m writing something in First Street Address textfield then at the same time content of Second Street Address text field should start changing. and same for all the other fields.

Thnaks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this delegate method

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string{
    NSString * toBeString = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range
                                                                withString:string];
    text2Field.text = toBeString;
    return YES;
}
```

In it first set the entered text to other textField and then **return YES**

Dont forget to return yes,

Comment: Thanks 4 ur post, Again u deserve a greate salute. I also tried anser posted by iNoob, then as said there is issue that If First field has been entered as say "XYZA" , second field has just "XYZ". Why is it so ?

Comment: Because when this delegate method is called, the text in the textfield is not updated.. It is asking "should I change characters in Range???" The range is given and u get string to replace. If you return YES, it will set value to the textfield.text, else it will continue with the old value. @Bhurudada

Answer (score 2):

Set both `textfield.delegate =self`

I just tried with :

```
  - (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
 {

    self.yourSecondField.text=self.yourFirstField.text;

     return YES;
 }
```

**Issue:** If First field has been entered as say "XYZA" , second field has just "XYZ", maybe someone can edit this answer or give a better one.

Comment: @Bhurudada No problem. Hope you found a better answer which takes care of issue i posted.

Answer (score 0):

for this functionality use this code

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField{
if (textField == street_Address) {
    if (check_box) {
        street_address.text=street_Address.text;
}
    else
        [street_Address resignFirstResponder ];}
```

similarly u apply for rest of other fields. First u check ur check box is enable or not. if enable then pass the value to below text fileds otherwise resign current text field.

Comment: ok then ur answer will help more.And sorry to all if my answer divert ur notice.

Comment: @ios perhaps you meant `street_address2.text = street_adress.text` ?

Comment: @ios there is no need to say sorry.. It is good thing that you are willing to share your knowledge here and trying to help others :)